# Multithread warning in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a problem with multithread. Warning is: "The method start() is undefined for the type MenuThread". What should I do

```
public void run() {
   if (whichMethodToCall == 1) {

   }
   else if (whichMethodToCall == 2) {

   }
}
```

Comment: define the run method?

Comment: @blahfunk run method is defined in MenuThread class.But other class which include above code, doesnt see start mthod. What should I do

Comment: post the code that defines your MenuThread class, please

Comment: First thing you need to do is to post MenuThread class' code ...

Comment: If your `MenuThread` class extends `Thread` it inherits the `start()` method. If your `MenuThread` class implements `Runnable` it has a `run()` method but obviously no `start()` method. Using `new Thread(thread).start()` in this case. But until you publish your code we don't know exactly.

Comment: edit your code. your curly braces are not matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MenuThread is implementing the `Runnable` interface. It is not a thread. If you it to run on a different thread pass an instance of MyThread to a Thread object

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new MenuThread(i));
 thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Thread(thread).start()`.

Answer (score 0):

*Problematic code:*

```
MenuThread thread = new MenuThread(i);
```

Above line create `MenuThread` which implements `Runnable` interface. Still it's not a thread and hence

`thread.start();` is illegal.

Right way to create Thread from `Runnable` instance

```
MenuThread thread = new MenuThread(i);
(new Thread(thread)).start();
```

You can create threads in two different ways. Have a look at oracle documentation about [thread creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

> An application that creates an instance of Thread must provide the code that will run in that thread. There are two ways to do this:

1. `Provide a Runnable object.` The `Runnable` interface defines a single method, run, meant to contain the code executed in the thread. `The Runnable object is passed to the Thread constructor`

   ```
   public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
       }
   }
   ```
2. `Subclass Thread`. The Thread class itself implements `Runnable`, though its run method does nothing. An application can subclass `Thread`, providing its own implementation of run

   ```
   public class HelloThread extends Thread {

       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           (new HelloThread()).start();
       }

   }
   ```